# Installing fetchmail - Not found in current repositories

Tags: apt, software-installation, fetchmail

**Background**

This is probably very basic for someone, but I can not figure this out for the life of me. I wish to simply install fetchmail onto my raspberry pi. Using the command `sudo apt-get install fetchmail` results in the following:

[image]

**What I have tried**

I have tried `sudo apt-get update` which goes through the process of updating, then follow with the install command for fetchmail shown above, but the same result.  Per fetchmail's [own page](https://www.fetchmail.info/fetchmail-FAQ.html) it states that the sources are also available at two repositories: https://gitlab.com/fetchmail/fetchmail and https://sourceforge.net/p/fetchmail/git/

I am not very experienced at adding repositories as my attempts have failed. I did take a look at `/etc/apt/sources.list` and tried to mimic the one found in here but it just results in errors for me.

I know this is probably very basic for most, but I really can't figure this out so much appreaciated!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that manually installing seems to work. I used:

`sudo wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/fetchmail/fetchmail_6.4.0~beta4-3+deb10u1_armhf.deb` to download the package followed by:

`sudo apt install  ./fetchmail_6.4.0~beta4-3+deb10u1_armhf.deb`

This appears to have worked. For anyone else experiencing this issue, take a look at this page: https://packages.debian.org/buster/fetchmail and pick the specific architecture you use. For the raspberry pi, it uses a armhf version.

Comment: This is equivalent of clicking an arbitrary `Download` button on some ad-infested website and running the downloaded binary. Do *not* circumvent the security mechanisms in the `apt` ecosystem - instead, fix whatever prevented you from retrieving the package through standard methods (usually by calling `apt update` again).

Comment: @anx I did try calling `apt-update` as you suggest but did not work. What else do you suggest other than telling me my answer is wrong?

Comment: Go through the standard diagnostics like `apt policy packagename` to figure out what is going on. (you will find many similar questions like yours, at least on suitable sites of the SE network, this one is for professional management)